# Making a program see another program's memory

Tags: c++, memory

There are tools such as TSearch, Cheat Engine, etc. These are hacking programs for viewing and modifying parts of memory of another program.

If I am to create a C++ program that can see and modify other program's memory, how can I do that? What are some of the things I should be looking for?

Comment: You should be aware that the OS won't necessarily let you do this.

Comment: `WriteProcessMemory` for windows may be a start point, but the writer process should have enough privileges (debug) to do that, I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a feature of C++, it's under the control of the OS itself.

For example, Windows provides the [ReadProcessMemory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API call so that you can get your grubby little hands on the memory of another process. And of course, the [equivalent for writing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well so you can cause even *more* damage :-)

All this depends on having the correct privileges as well.

I'm not sure how Linux provides this but earlier UNIXes had "memory mapping" files like `/dev/mem` so you could get at the memory. There may be a per-process variant in the `procfs` file system which can give you access to the virtual memory of a specific process. That'd be the first place I'd start looking although others here will undoubtedly know more about that than I.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is to [write your own debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679288%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

That won't be easy, though. Good luck.